# Out of memory error when multiplying two very large sparse matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a very large sparse tall `matrixA` of size (`M x N` , `M` >>>>> `N`)
and other `matrixB` of size `N x 1`

I want to do

```
MatrixA*MatrixB
```

and get `M x 1` output. But I get an out of memory error. The matrices only have a couple of 100 nonzero elements. What's the way around this?

Comment: Are both `A` and `B` constructed using `sparse`? If `B` is `full` then the result will be `full`.

Comment: both A and B are sparse

Comment: What does `memory` and `whos` return?

Comment: linux apparently doesn't have memory. whos for one of the variables is
 MatrixA                    31679201751184x2                   90953480  double             sparse

Comment: You should reconsider your stance on "a couple of 100 elements" :) Oh, you mean nonzeros. What's `nnz(MatrixA)` and `nnz(MatrixB)`?

Comment: nnz(MatrixA) is in range of a few 100's
nnz(MatrixB) is 4

Comment: If `MatrixB` is *this* sparse, and reliably so, than you could compute the matrix product manually: loop over the nonzeros of `MatrixB` and put together the product piecewise. Is that an option?

Comment: It is, Is there a concise way of doing this?

Comment: Well, if `find()` works for your huge sparse case, you could do `[k,l]=find(MatrixB);`, then construct a sparse matrix with elements `sum_k MatrixA(m,k)*MatrixB(k,l)` (pseudocode, obviously) for each `m,l` index (`m` goes over the nonzeros of `MatrixA`).

Comment: I ended up doing something similar @AndrasDeak would you like to add that as an answer?

Comment: @Rahul I suggested to an earlier answerer to add this solution to their answer; but it seems they've deleted their answer by now. So I went ahead and added my own, please let me know if I should add something. I also edited your title and added some formatting, feel free to change/revert if you disagree with any of it:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [**@patrik**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2903371/patrik) noted in a now-deleted answer, the problem is that MATLAB stores sparse matrices column-wise rather than elementwise. This means that empty columns of your sparse matrix take up a tiny amount of memory, and a *huge* number of empty columns takes up an excessive amount of memory, even when the overall nonzero elements are reasonably few. A corresponding quote from one of your comments:

> `whos` for one of the variables is `MatrixA 31679201751184x290953480 double sparse`

I believe my saying "*huge*" is a bit of an understatement.

Since you've noted in comments that your matrices, especially the second one, contain *very* few nonzero elements, it's possibly quicker, but definitely feasible and more memory-efficient to implement the matrix product yourself.

Pick the nonzero indices of your matrices using `find`, then loop over these nonzeros of your matrices to construct the matrix product. The only thing you need is that (with some math-based pseudocode)

```
[MatrixA * MatrixB](m,l) = sum_k MatrixA(m,k)*MatrixB(k,l)
```

The indices you need for this all come from the vectors

```
[kvec, lvec] = find(MatrixB);
[mvec, ~] = find(MatrixA);
```

which especially in your case will be very light on the `lvec` side. After some preallocation it should be straightforward to loop over `mvec` and `lvec`, summing up the necessary terms with respect to elements of `kvec` along the way.

---

If your `matrixB` is indeed just a column vector, then your job is even easier: then you need

```
[MatrixA * MatrixB](m,1) = sum_k MatrixA(m,k)*MatrixB(k,1)
```

for which you essentially need

```
k1vec = find(MatrixB);
[mvec, k2vec] = find(MatrixA);

%// choose those 'k' indices which are nonzero in both matrices
both_k = intersect(k1vec,k2vec);
inds_A = ismember(k2vec,both_k);
inds_B = ismember(k1vec,both_k);
mvec = mvec(inds_A);
k2vec = k2vec(inds_A);
k1vec = k1vec(inds_B);
```

then constructing the product vector after preallocation.

Comment: Thanks! this is better then what I implemented

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference: If your N is small enough I found that this implementation works faster

```
function out = sparseMult(MatrixA, MatrixB)
out = sparse(size(a,1),1);
k1vec = find(b');
for i = k1vec
    out = out + a(:,i).*b(i);
end
end
```